# Does sequelize unique constraint retries if random value is not unique?

Tags: sequelize.js

Suppose you have unique constraint on a value and default value is being generated by a function that generates a random hash of say 4 digits. I need it to be unique and random. Since 4 is small number there would be times when value generated would be duplicate. In that case I want sequelize to try again. My question is does it try again?

IF not what's is the best way to tell sequelize to automatically generate default value for certain column that is x digits long, is unique and random.

Comment: Have you checked the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that something like this :

```
funtion createRandom(value){
    let randomNumber = generateRandomNumber(); // function or script that genrates random string
    xyz.create({ x : value , y : randomNumber }).then(() => {
        // handle your success response
    }).catch(err => {
        createRandom(value); // call the function again recursively until success
    })
}
```